# "Class not found" when trying to use composer auto load for a wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, composer-php

I'm writing a plugin and trying to use composer to auto load my classes, but I'm unable to get it working. I know there are a lot of questions on this topic but nothing seems to work for me.

directory structure:

- plugin-name

  - classes

    - Class_Name.php
  - vendor
  - plugin-name.php
  - composer.json
  - composer.lock

**composer.json** file:

```
{
    "require": {
        "katzgrau/klogger": "dev-master"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "Foo\\": "classes" }
    }
}
```

**plugin-name.php** file:

```
namespace Plugins_Main;

use Foo\Class_Name;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

class Plugin_Name_Bootstrap{
    public static function run() {
        Class_Name::instance();
    }
 }
add_action('plugins_loaded', array('Plugins_Main\Plugin_Name_Bootstrap', 'run'));
```

**Class_Name.php** file:

```
namespace Foo;

class Class_Name{
    protected static $_instance = null;

    public static function instance(){
        if ( self::$_instance === null ) {
            self::$_instance = new self();
        }

        return self::$_instance;
    }
}
```

According to the docs this autoloading should work, but I'm still getting

> Class 'Foo\Class_Name' not found

I thought maybe it related somehow to the fact that I'm trying to initialize "Class_Name" in plugins_loaded hook, But why would that matter if I'm require vendor/autoload.php much earlier?

Comment: I think the problem is that you are doing `use Foo\Class_Name;` before `require 'vendor/autoload.php';`. Try doing `require` before `use` :)

Comment: Still doesn't work :/

Comment: Hm maybe it is unable to read the autoload then, try replacing `require 'vendor/autoload.php';` with `require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';`

Comment: that solves the problem.. thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Needed to require autoload.php with `__DIR__`:

from

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

to

```
require __DIR__  . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

Thanks [Damian Dziaduch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2120073/damian-dziaduch) for the answer.